# New sink and faucet but no water?

Tags: faucet, sink

So i installed a new sink and faucet even shut off valves and lines.  But when i went to turn on faucet it only dribbles out water. I turned the water off at the water heater and i know some times it can take a few mins to build up the pressure.  But everywhere else has good pressure.  I even took off the line and turned the shut off to check pressure it was fine.  I then got different lines but still no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a kitchen sink? Does the cold water also have low flow or is it only the hot that has low flow?

Comment: What was the resolution?  If suggest detaching a supply line and briefly turning it on to see if it's flowing well there...

Answer (score 2):

There is often debris from manufacturing, sometimes dislodged during shipping.

The first thing to try is to unscrew the aerator and clean it. If it still has problems with the aerator but works fine without it then the problem is the aerator.

If it doesn't work well even without the aerator installed then something is wrong in the cartridge or other innards of the faucet. Faucets typically come with a parts diagram for replacement parts, but if it comes to taking it all apart then I would just take it back to the store, particularly if you got it from one of the big box stores that has easy returns/replacements.

But my bet is the aerator.